# hmmlearn: how to get the prediction for the hidden state probability at time T+1, given a full observation sequence 1:T

Tags: python, hidden-markov-models, hmmlearn

I'm using hmmlearn's GaussianHMM to train a Hidden Markov Model with Gaussian observations. Each hidden state k has its corresponding Gaussian parameters: mu_k, Sigma_k.

After training the model, I would like to calculate the following quantity:

P(z_{T+1} = j | x_{1:T}),

where j = 1, 2, ... K, K is the number of hidden states.

The above probability is basically the one-step-ahead hidden state probabilities, given a full sequence of observations: x_1, x_2, ..., x_T, where x_i, i=1,...,T are used to train the HMM model.

I read the [documentation](http://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html), but couldn't find a function to calculate this probability. Is there any workaround?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The probability you are looking for is simply one row of the transition matrix. The n-th row of the transition matrix gives the probability of transitioning to each state at time `t+1` knowing the state the system is at time `t`.

In order to know in which state the system is at time `t` given a sequence of observations `x_1,...,x_t` one can use the Viterbi algorithm which is the default setting of the method `predict` in `hmmlearn`.

```
model = hmm.GaussianHMM(n_components=3, covariance_type="full", n_iter=100)  # Viterbi is set by default as the 'algorithm' optional parameter.
model.fit(data)
state_sequence = model.predict(data)
prob_next_step = model.transmat_[state_sequence[-1], :]
```

I suggest you give a closer look at this [documentation](https://hmmlearn.readthedocs.io/en/latest/tutorial.html#training-hmm-parameters-and-inferring-the-hidden-states) that shows concrete use examples.

Comment: Thanks for sharing. This is also what I came up with. Just wanted to add, after the `.predict` call via the Viterbi traceback algorithm, the class probabilities at time `T+1` are: `model.transmat_[state_sequence[-1], :]`

Comment: I added it to my answer. Thanks ;)

Answer (score 0):

Once the an HMM `model` is trained, you can get the `t+1` state given `1:t` observations `X` as following:

```
import numpy as np
from sklearn.utils import check_random_state
sates = model.predict(X)
transmat_cdf = np.cumsum(model.transmat_, axis=1)
random_sate = check_random_state(model.random_state)
next_state = (transmat_cdf[states[-1]] > random_state.rand()).argmax()
```

the `t+1` state is generated according to the `t` state and the `transmat_`